Structured stream writer using foreachBatch does not respect shuffle.partitions parameter
We are running a data deduplication operation on a structured stream using the foreachBatch functionality.
However, the write operation does not appear to respect the number of shuffle partitions that we set within the workbook using
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","auto")
The number of shuffle partitions seems to be the default 200, which is suboptimal in our case. Also - before upgrading the pyspark version to 3.5.0 - the jobs kept crashing. Now there are 200 jobs running for a very long time.
Any suggestions?

To answer my own question: need to set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions prior to running the stream, and cannot use "auto".
